# If $\sum x_k=\frac12$, then $\prod\frac{1-x_k}{1+x_k}\geq\frac13$

Tags: inequality

The question is this

> The sum of positive numbers $x_1,x_2,x_3,\dotsc,x_n$ is $\frac{1}{2}$. Prove that $$\frac{1-x_1}{1+x_1}\cdot\frac{1-x_2}{1+x_2}\cdot\frac{1-x_3}{1+x_3}\cdots\frac{1-x_n}{1+x_n}\geq\frac{1}{3}.$$

My process was something like this:

> Using Weirstrass' Inequality in the numerators, we get $$\prod_{i=1}^{n}(1-x_i)>1-\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i)=1-\frac12=\frac12.$$ So now we need to prove that $$\prod_{i=1}^{n}(1+x_i)<\frac32.$$

But then, again using Weirstrass' Inequality, we get $$\prod_{i=1}^{n}(1+x_i)>1+\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i)=\frac32.$$

So now I'm stuck. Please help me solve this problem.

Note: This question if from Mathematical Circles (Russian Experience) so I don't think that this question is supposed to be wrong

Comment: From my experience, using strict inequalities when the question involves non-strict inequalities usually leads nowhere.

Comment: @user92774 So how do you suggest that I move forward? I think that the equality holds iff there is only one term,i.e, $x_i$ .  For that case, equality holds even in my process.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the case.

Comment: Using AM-GM one can guess that $S \geq (\frac{2n-1}{2n+1})^n \geq \frac{1}{3}$ but I wouldn't know how to formalize that argument.

Comment: @user92774 I had tried to do what you guessed and obtained the numerator, but I was unable to get the denominator.

Comment: Induction seems to be the way to go here, since both numerator and denominator, if treated separately, will have the same direction of inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will prove it using induction over $n$.

1. It is seen that for $n=1$ it follows that $x_{1} = \frac{1}{2}$. Then
   $$
    \frac{1-x_{1}}{1+x_{1}} = \frac{1}{3}.
   $$
2. Assume it holds for $n=k$, then for $n = k+1$, we have $\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} x_{i} = \frac{1}{2}$. Define the element $y_{i} = x_{i}$ for $i=1, \ldots,n-1$ and $y_{n} = x_{n}+x_{n+1}$. Then still $\sum_{i=1}^{k} y_{i} = \frac{1}{2}$ and by assumption we have:
   $$
    \frac{1-y_{1}}{1+y_{1}} \cdot \frac{1-y_{2}}{1+y_{2}} \cdots \frac{1-y_{k}}{1+y_{k}} \geq \frac{1}{3}.
   $$
   It is seen that
   $$
    \frac{1-x_{k}}{1+x_{k}} \cdot \frac{1-x_{k+1}}{1+x_{k+1}} = \frac{1 - x_{k} - x_{k+1} + x_{k} x_{k+1}}{1+ x_{k} + x_{k+1} + x_{k} x_{k+1}} > \frac{1 - x_{k} -x_{k+1}}{1+x_{k}+x_{k+1}} = \frac{1-y_{k}}{1+y_{k}}.
   $$
   Combining, we have:
   $$
    \frac{1-x_{1}}{1+x_{1}} \frac{1-x_{2}}{1+x_{2}} \cdots \frac{1-x_{k}}{1+x_{k}} \cdot \frac{1-x_{k+1}}{1+x_{k+1}} \geq \frac{1-y_{1}}{1+y_{1}} \cdot \frac{1-y_{2}}{1+y_{2}} \cdots \frac{1-y_{k}}{1+y_{k}} \geq \frac{1}{3}.
   $$

Comment: Comparing your proof with mine, I see that I tried to prove $\frac{1-x_k}{1+x_k}\frac{1-x_{k+1}}{1+x_{k+1}}>\frac{1-y_k}{1+y_k}$ by taking the numerator and denominator separately. I suppose that is where I made my mistake.

Comment: It is. Remains one question for me: given a number $n$ what positive (or non-negative) $x_{i}$ do I need to choose such that the product is maximal. It seems to me that this is maximal if we choose $x_{i} = \frac{1}{2 n}$ all equal. The maximum would then be $\left( \frac{2n - 1}{2n + 1} \right)^{n} \to \frac{1}{e}$ if $n \to \infty$.

Comment: @Vincent You can prove the maximum by smoothing. Show that for $ a < c < b \leq 1/2$, we have  $ (1-a)/(1+b)(1-b)/(1+b) \leq (1-c)/(1+c) ( 1-a-b+c)/(1+a+b-c )$. So we replace the extreme elements  with $ 1/2n, a+b - 1/2n$ and repeat that.

Answer (score 1):

As you say in the comment, equality holds if there is just one positive $x_i$.

We need to prove that adding another positive $x_j$ (and thereby reducing $x_i$) will increase the ratio.

Let $x_j = x$ and $x_i = \frac{1}{2} - x$.

Then the ratio is
$\frac{(1 - x)(\frac{1}{2} +x)}{(1+ x)(\frac{3}{2} - x)} = \frac{\frac{1}{2} + x(\frac{1}{2} - x)}{\frac{3}{2} + x(\frac{1}{2} - x)} \ge \frac{\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{3}{2}} =  \frac{1}{3}$.

Can you extend that argument ?by induction
 on the number of terms?

Comment: I did try it, but it proved too difficult (at least for me).

Comment: @ oks: Oops, saw your hint, only after I copied down mine, took me some time.

Comment: @Vincent nice, thank you!